# MemoryStream vs. FileStream: Document Viewer rendering document from filestream successfully but not memorystream?

Tags: c#, silverlight, pdf, stream, streaming

I'm using C1's PDF viewer control in a silverlight application and am testing max PDF size limitations.
I have a PDF that's 35MB.

When I load the PDF viewer through the OpenFileDialog simply sending it the filestream it renders fine. All 900 pages.

However, when I attempt to load the PDF viewer through a MemoryStream created from a byte[] it renders nothing. It does not error out, it simply renders blank.

This is the exact same document. And the MemoryStream process works successfully with significantly smaller PDF documents. Yet the FileStream method works with larger documents so I know it's not a limitation of the PDF viewer, correct?

FileStream method:

```
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        bool? res = ofd.ShowDialog();
        if (res == true)
        {
            FileStream stream = ofd.File.OpenRead();
            docViewer.LoadDocument(stream);
        }
```

MemoryStream method:

```
       imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
       MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
       stream.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
       stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
       docViewer.LoadDocument(stream);
```

This gave me the same results. Blank viewer:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
{
      docViewer.LoadDocument(stream);
}
```

Again...frustrated by failure.
I refactored the call to use "OpenReadAsync", then I altered my API call (we're using MVC as a pseudo API) to return the stream and it's still rendering blank.
The result internal stream's length is correct too.

Client Call:

```
        string url = App.Server + "Document/RetrievePDFTest";
        try
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Result != null)
                {
                    docViewer.LoadDocument(e.Result);
                }
            });
            wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO - handle exception
        }
```

Server API:

```
    public ActionResult RetrievePDFTest()
    {
        return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("D://temp//repositories//test35mb.PDF"), "application/pdf");
    }
```

UPDATE!!!!
I believe I've found what might be an issue.

Within my silverlight application I'm actually popping this document viewer in a new window, then I'm sending that new window the information by which to retrieve the PDF image from teh server. In essence, I'm telling it which document to retrieve by a key I'm passing:

```
this.windowManager.NavigateToPageInNewWindow("/Views/pdfViewerUserControl.xaml");
                LocalMessageSender s = new LocalMessageSender("receiver", LocalMessageSender.Global);
                s.SendAsync(doc.Barcode);
```

Now, in my pdfViewerUserControl.xaml, in it's constructor I'm creating and registering the listener for the message:

```
public pdfViewerUserControl()
    {
        LocalMessageReceiver messageReceiver = new LocalMessageReceiver("receiver", ReceiverNameScope.Global, LocalMessageReceiver.AnyDomain);
        messageReceiver.MessageReceived += messageReceiver_MessageReceived;
        try
        {
            messageReceiver.Listen();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        // Required to initialize variables
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

In the "messageReceiver_MessageReceived" event handler, this is where I make my server call to retrieve the image and load the viewer. This process is resulting in a blank PDF viewer even though the server returns the image. (even the LARGE pdf)

NOW, as a test tool I also have a test button on the page, this button triggers an event in the code behind that makes the exact same server call, and loads the result in the exact same way but this works!!! The large 35MB PDF is rendered successfully in teh viewer.

This leads me to believe there's a disconnect when using the LocalMessageSender/LocalMessageReceiver objects.

Comment: Could you please include the code where `imageBytes` is populated?

Comment: Where are you filling imageBytes - have you checked that array? Does it contain encoded data (as in file) or header + pixel buffer?

Comment: What happens if you open a filestream and copy it to the memory stream?

Comment: Again, the MemoryStream method works fine with a smaller file. It renders it through the exact same process.
I'm simply doing a "File.ReadAllByes()" to populate imageBytes.

The reason I cannot simply use a filestream is because the physical files are located on the server. The filepath is designated by what the user chooses on the client.

Comment: Why aren't you just calling `new MemoryStream(imageBytes)` out of interest?

Comment: Ultimately you'll be fetching stuff from the web server which will mean at some point the bytes in question are going to be in a Stream provided by a `WebResponse`.  Is there a reason you aren't just plugging that stream directly in to `LoadDocument` ?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, that had same results, that's how I initially had it.
I tried this in an effort to overcome this problem.

Comment: @Anthony, I'm using SL's WebClient DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs to store a serialized object with this byte array as a property of that transfer object.

Comment: @MVelasquez: You shouldn't be using *DownloadString* for binary data, surely.

Comment: @Jon, either way, the matter at hand doesn't change because the data is being sent across successfully.

Comment: @Jon is quite right, you are not still doing this mad base64 thing are you? I thought you had decided to add another service that just sent the PDF bytes as is?

Comment: @Anthony, yes I added another call to return the bytes as is. Which is how it began working successfully. Then I began testing with larger sized files. Again it DOES WORK. I might simply have to cap the size of the files requested.

Comment: Can you post the PDF you are testing with + minimal sample code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @Sander, I've actually narrowed it down further and found that it is not the PDF itself, but the means by which I'm retrieving it. It seems that when retrieving it and loading it into the docviewer using the LocalMessageReceiver event, it's failing. But when I retrieve it and load it using a simple button click event handler, it succeeds. Can anyone see why a LocalMessageReceiver received event would bear different results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue has nothing to do with the viewer or the PDF file at all. It has to do with some issue of not being able to manipulate the UI in the context that I'm in.

I'm popping a new window using HtmlPage.PopupWindow() specifying another usercontrol (my pdf XAML user control which contains the pdfviewer) as the URI.

In order to pass that new window the key of which document to retrieve/view, I registered a listener on that new window's user control.
Then I send that listener the key.

Well in the listener's message received event, I'm making the call to get the byte array and populate the viewer.

This seems to not be updating the UI. Instead, I've ditched the listener/sender pattern and simply tacked the key onto the end of the URI to the "HtmlPage.PopupWindow()".
Then in the constructor of the new user control page, I extrapolate the key from the URI and "bob's your uncle", it works.

I'm still unsure of whether I was on a separate thread, or what was going on with the listener's "on message received" event.
I was hitting the breakpoint in the listener, the doc viewer's "LoadDocument()" method was not erroring our or throwing an exception, the UI just simply was not rendering the update.

Answer (score 2):

Given the comments, I suspect the problem is that you're downloading it as a string and then converting it into bytes. Compare the data in the byte array with the data in the file (e.g. take an MD5 hash).

To download binary data, you should be using `DownloadData` instead.

Comment: The WebClient object has no "DownloadData" method.
In any case, this method works successfully with other documents I've tested.

Comment: @MVelasquez: Use `OpenReadAsync` method and the `OpenReadCompleted` event the `Result` property of the event args is the Stream you are after.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Thx for being patient with me guys. Will report back.

Comment: @MVelasquez: Time to dig out fiddler and check what is actually being sent by the server.  Try saving the response entity body as PDF, does it open in the standard reader?

Comment: I've actually narrowed it down further and found that it is not the PDF itself, but the means by which I'm retrieving it. It seems that when retrieving it and loading it into the docviewer using the LocalMessageReceiver event, it's failing. But when I retrieve it and load it using a simple button click event handler, it succeeds. Can anyone see why a LocalMessageReceiver received event would bear different results?

Comment: @MVelasquez: Sorry, DownloadData isn't in the Silverlight version. I was on a flaky 3G connection and couldn't check. It still seems odd to me to transfer *binary* data via a string - how are you making sure you're not losing data that way? It's not clear exactly how the transfer is being handled. How exactly are you getting the byte array?

Comment: @Jon, on the server, in an MVC "pseudo-REST" API the server has access to the file on the server. It's given a key of the document. It retrieves the path to the document specified by key from the DB. It then performs a File.ReadAllByes() on that filepath. I have a serializable transfer object to hold that byte array as a property. I serialize the object and send it across the wire to my client. On the client side, I deserialize that transfer object and have access to the byte array as a property of the object.

Comment: @MVelasquez: So how do you send the object on the wire? That's the important bit. Because you're dealing with arbitrary binary data, but you're downloading it as a string. If you're using base64, that's fine  - if you're not, that's a significant problem.

Comment: @Jon How does XML serialization of an object handle byte array properties? That's how it's being sent. I don't know the underlying logic in serialization, but I'm simply creating an object. One of the properties on that object is a byte array. I'm setting that property as my byte array, serializing the object to an XML string, then sending it across. Then deserializing to the same object type and I have access to my byte array property.

Comment: @MVelasquez: Right, that'll be in Base64 then, I suspect. I would still check whether there are any differences between the arrays in the "working" case and the "failing" case.

Comment: Oh, no Jon, you didn't see my update did you? It turns out that when I went without doing the base64 conversion the image never had any issues again. It became a problem with the UI not updating for some reason. See my "Answer".

Comment: @MVelasquez: I saw your updated question but found it hard to follow, especially as you have only provided snippets, never showing what you do with the string.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason could be memory stream object has to be disposed at the end.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Do something with ms..
}
```

or say this at end of using memory stream object

```
stream.Dispose();
stream.Close();
```